# Paint BW texture, if used color stencil

Tags: texturing, image, texture-painting

I want draw Roughness map. It may be in BW mode, but I use color stencil. It is possible draw in BW mode (not color)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the Texture Properties, and expand the *Color* panel, you can set the *Saturation* to 0. The colors will output in shades of gray.

[image]

Comment: How I didn’t think of it myself? Thank!